# Daily rollover for a FileOutputStream using Protocol Buffers?

Tags: java, log4j, protocol-buffers, fileoutputstream

I am getting a stream of data from a server (in binary format). This data is serialised using Google protocol buffers. I'm attempting to do a daily rollover (i.e. if next day occurs write to new file containing the new Date with the compressed data inside).

I've attempted to do this via log4j, however, log4j doesn't account for binary (as far as I know I can only get text via it). When log4j writes the files, it doesn't write them in binary, but in text (human readable) format.

I went over this question to create a custom binary appender in log4j [How to Create Binary Log File in Java using Log4J](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827568/how-to-create-binary-log-file-in-java-using-log4j)

However, I only started with log4j a couple of days ago and I'm not too sure how to go about doing this.

Is there any other way to do the rollover for binary data? I'm not even sure if log4j is the best solution. I'm more than happy to try any solution you can come up with!

I want log4j to write the data in Binary not Text.

Is there any way to do a daily rollover for binary files in java?

Comment: Why don't you open files yourself?

Comment: @talex What do you mean?

Comment: Just open FileInputStream and write what you want. At midnight close it and open another one.

Comment: What do you need to keep the data you get from the server for? Just for back-ups? What meta-data do you need to store along with the data from the server? Just the time the data was received?

If the data is important, I'd probably want to store it in a database and use a BLOB for the ProtoBuff data.

If you're sure a textual log file is sufficient, I would encode the ProtoBuff data in an ASCII-format, such as Base64, so that when you view the log file with a text editor, it will be readable.

Comment: Is it possible to convert the raw protobuf text into serialised protobuf binary?

Comment: can you please explain what you mean by *rollover* i'm no native speaker and my translations don't make any sense when searching for rollover... (i just know "to rollover a credit" means to get more time on that credit)

Comment: Say you are writing to File 1, if you don't want File 1 to exceed 100megabytes in size, you would stop writing to File 1, and then you create and write to another file called File 2 (and keep writing to that) and so on and so on. This would be a way of controlling the file sizes. The problem I have is that log4j doesn't do "rollovers" for serialised data. It takes them as raw string. I want log4j to write it was serialised data. Here is a tutorial: http://www.codejava.net/coding/configure-log4j-for-creating-daily-rolling-log-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think log4j is necessary here. If you need just file rollover small stream wrapper would be enough.

Jetty project has implementation of such FileOuputStream in it's util classes [RolloverFileRotator](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/master/jetty-util/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/util/RolloverFileOutputStream.java) which I think fits perfectly here.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the default log4j DailyRollingFileAppender and include it in your classpath

```
package test.com;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;

public class BinaryRollingFileAppender extends DailyRollingFileAppender {

    FileOutputStream fout;

    public BinaryRollingFileAppender(){
    }

    @Override
    public void setFile(String file) {
        super.setFile(file);
        try {
            fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void append(LoggingEvent le) {
        try {
            fout.write((byte[])le.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean requiresLayout() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        try {
            fout.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

then configure the appender via log4j properties file

```
log4j.appender.app=test.com.BinaryRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.app.File=/tmp/binary.bin
log4j.appender.app.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.logger.app.com=DEBUG, app
```

and test it

```
package test.com;

import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class TestBinary {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(TestBinary.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path path = Paths.get("c://tmp/binary-example-file.bin");
        try {
            LOGGER.debug(Files.readAllBytes(path));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if this is what you want, but is a good start point, hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi, i have doubt in your example.
How the LOGGER instance in your TestBinary uses the custom BinaryRollingFileAppender?
Going through some custom appender examples i saw people creating the custom appender instance and appending it to LOGGER instance. Is this how we attach custom appender to LOGGER or any other way?

Comment: Via log4j properties file, line 1, log4j.appender.app=test.com.BinaryRollingFileAppender, that line defines the appender class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RotatingFileOutputStream` with `DailyRotationPolicy` provided by [rotating-fos](https://github.com/vy/rotating-fos) Java library.